# Computing Triple Integrals of Splines Fast

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to replicate a result from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.1652.pdf), specifically in page 22, the function

$$ I_1(s,s') = \max_{\phi \geq 2} \iiint\limits_{1/s' \leq t\leq u
\leq v \leq 1/s} \omega \left( \frac{\phi - t- u - v}{u} \right)
\frac{dt \, du \, dv}{tu^2v} $$

where $\omega(u)$ is the Buchstab
function, defined by the following  delay differential equation.

\begin{aligned} &\omega(u) = 1/u &&  1 \leq u \leq 2 \\  &(u
\omega(u))' = \omega(u-1) && u \geq 2 \end{aligned}

I already have the Buchstab function implemented as a piecewise set of Taylor
polynomials $\omega_n(u)$, one for each interval $[n,n+1]$. Directly
trying to compute the integration naively gets the computer stuck.
Numerically integrating over the region in question seems to work:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[t <= u <= v] w[(p - t - u - v)/u]*1/(t*u^2*v),
           {t, 1/sp, 1/s}, {u, 1/sp, 1/s}, {v, 1/sp, 1/s}]
```

but it's painfully slow. Any tips for getting this to run in reasonable
time? Would numerically solving the differential equation and then
trying to integrate that be better?

The definition of the Buchstab function I'm using follows
from [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1990-1023043-8) (pages 137-138). We compute $\omega(u)$ by defining

$$\omega_j(u) = \omega(u), \; j \leq u \leq j+1$$

We have the following relation

$$u\omega_{j+1}(u) = \int_j^{u-1} \omega_j(t) dt + (j+1)\omega_j(j+1)$$

For each $\omega_j$, we expand it into a power series about $u=j+1$.

$$\omega_j(u) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(j) (u-(j+1))^k$$

We have $\omega_2(u)$ in exact form by the above relation, but the rest are hard to determine in closed form, as the repeat integrations get worse and worse.

$$\omega_2(u) = \frac{\log(u-1) + 1}{u}$$

I determined that the $a_k(j)$ coefficients are defined recursively,

\begin{align}
a_0(2) &= \frac{1 + \log 2}{3} \\
a_k(2) &= (-1)^{k+1}
\left(
-\frac{1+\log 2}{3^{k+1}} + \frac{1}{3(2^k)} \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k-m}
\left( \frac{2}{3}\right)^m
\right) \\
a_0(j) &= a_0(j-1) + \frac{1}{j+1} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} a_k(j-1) \\
a_k(j) &= \frac{a_{k-1}(j-1) - ka_{k-1}(j)}{k(j+1)}
\end{align}

So I implement all this in *Mathematica*, and check it against the numerical solution to the DDE, and it all matches up.

```
wN[u_] := Evaluate[w[u] /.
NDSolve[{D[u*w[u], u] == w[u - 1], w[u /; u <= 2] == u^-1},
w, {u, 1, 30}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]];

w2Exact[u_] := (Log[u - 1] + 1)/u;

degreeTaylor = 10;

w2A[u_] := Evaluate[N[Normal[Series[w2Exact[u], {u,3,degreeTaylor}]],
MachinePrecision]];

w2Coeff = CoefficientList[w2A[u + 3], u];

a[k_, 2] := a[k, 2] = w2Coeff[[k + 1]];

a[0, j_] := a[0, j] = a[0, j - 1] + 1/(j + 1) Sum[(-1)^k/(k + 1)
*a[k,j - 1], {k, 1, degreeTaylor}];

a[k_, j_] := a[k, j] = 1/(j + 1) (a[k - 1, j - 1]/k - a[k - 1, j]);

w3A[u_] := Evaluate[Sum[a[k, 3]*(u - 4)^k, {k, 0, degreeTaylor}]];
w4A[u_] := Evaluate[Sum[a[k, 4]*(u - 5)^k, {k, 0, degreeTaylor}]];

wA[u_] := Piecewise[{
{u^-1, 1 <= u < 2},
{w2A[u], 2 <= u < 3},
{w3A[u], 3 <= u < 4},
{w4A[u], 4 <= u < 5},
{Exp[-EulerGamma], u >=  5}}];
```

Here `wN` is the numerical solution, and `wA` is my approximation. Plotting the two shows my approximation is good, and can be made as precise as needed.

```
LogPlot[Abs[wA[u] - wN[u]], {u, 1, 6}];
```

(I'm aware there is probably a better way to do it instead of having all
these separate `wnA` functions, but trying something of the form `wA[u_,n_]` had issues I couldn't resolve.)

I add in as many $w_j$ terms as need be (for examples sake I'm only going up to $\omega_j(4)$ here), and increase the degree of the power series (here, only 10 terms) and then set it to its limiting constant
$e^{-\gamma}$ after some point to obtain the accuracy needed.

It was done in this way so that the absolute error of my approximation to Buchstab could be computed in a rigorous manner, following the paper.

Comment: For reference, could you include the definition you're using for the Buchstab function? And yes, `NDSolve[]` supports DDEs, so you might want to try that, too.

Comment: I'm having an awful lot of trouble formatting it, I've indented the code correctly and such, but I keep getting kicked back by the automated formatting checker, and it doesn't tell me where it's got a problem.

Comment: For now, can you try pasting it into [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com), and then somebody else can try formatting it into this post?

Comment: That's a good idea,
https://pastebin.com/7S4WDc9r

Comment: P.S. *[Mathematics of Computation](http://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journalsframework/mcom)* is freely accessible from AMS; I've replaced your JStor link because of this.

Answer (score 2):

The **Buchstab function** is the unique continuous function $w : \mathbb{R}_{\ge 1} \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ defined by the *delay differential equation* $u\,w(u) = 1 \; \, (1 \le u \le 2)$, $(u\,w(u))' = w(u - 1) \; \, (u > 2)$ ([Panario, 1998](http://algo.inria.fr/seminars/sem97-98/panario.pdf)). It approaches the asymptotic value $w(u) \to e^{-\gamma} \approx 0.561459$ as $u \to \infty$ (and in fact has nearly reached this value already by $u \approx 4$).

In [The Mathematica GuideBook for Numerics | Michael Trott | Springer](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=Do1Opir9guIC&pg=PA386) propose the following numerical solution, which I have taken care to copy in *Mathematica*:

```
BuchstabFunctionList =
FixedPointList[{(* integration interval start point *) #[[1]] + 1,
        NDSolve[{D[z w[z], z] == #[[2]][[1, 1, 2]][z - 1],
                   (* solve differential equation *)
                   w[#[[1]] + 1] == #[[2]][[1, 1, 2]][#[[1]] + 1]}, w,
                   {z, #[[1]] + 1, #[[1]] + 2},
                   WorkingPrecision -> 40 , MaxSteps -> 10^4,
                   PrecisionGoal -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 20]} &,
                 (* solution in interval [1, 2] *)
                 {1, {{w[z] -> (1/# &)} }},
                 (* solve until values at endpoints coincide *)
                 SameTest -> ((#1[[2, 1, 1, 2]][#1[[1]] + 1] == 
                               #2[[2, 1, 1, 2]][#2[[1]] + 1]) &)];

BuchstabFunction[x_] := 
        BuchstabFunctionList[[IntegerPart[x]]][[2, 1, 1, 2]][x];

Plot[{BuchstabFunction[x], Exp[-EulerGamma]}, 
     {x, 1, Length[BuchstabFunctionList] + 1}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {1, 1}, 
     AxesLabel -> {u, w[u]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, {0.5, 1}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, {Blue, Dashed}}]
```

[image: Plot Buchstab function]

See if it can come in handy.

Comment: Thankfully, solving DDEs is easier these days, compared to the time Trott wrote that code: `NDSolve[{u ω'[u] + ω[u] == ω[u - 1], ω[u /; u <= 2] == 1/u}, ω, {u, 1, 30}]`.

Comment: In this case, [the DDE docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDelayDifferentialEquations.html) gives some nice examples.

Comment: The interval $[1,2]$ is implicitly taken care of by `ω[u /; u <= 2] == 1/u` and starting the integration at `1`.